# Error: The constructor CellSignalStrengthGsm() is not visible

Tags: java, android

When i try this code:

```
CellSignalStrengthGsm Abc = new CellSignalStrengthGsm();
```

I get the following error in eclipse:

```
"The constructor CellSignalStrengthGsm() is not visible".
```

The full source code is [here](https://code.google.com/p/android-source-browsing/source/browse/telephony/java/android/telephony/CellSignalStrengthGsm.java?repo=platform--frameworks--base&r=c6e4917adda19beb780386bcc26b652748b8ab13)

In the source file I have noticed the following:

```
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
/**
     * Empty constructor
     *
     * @hide
     */
    public CellSignalStrengthGsm() {
        setDefaultValues();
    }

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @hide

""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
```

Now my question is what does the above comment means
and how to get an object of CellSignalStrengthGsm ?

Thanks in advance for help, I am new to android and java programming, sorry if i am asking any basic question.

Answer (score 0):

@hide is an annotation.  It alters the code, either at compile time or at run time.  In this case, its a compile time change that tells the compiler not to let anyone call this, even though its public.  This is generally used when you have to make a function public to fit an interface, but you don't want anyone to actually call it.

WHy are you trying to make one of these anyway?  Generally you're passed one of these, there's no reason to construct one (outside of maybe a test)-  you don't have the information to make an accurate one.

Comment: I am trying to use the method  getDbm() and getAsuLevel() in that class. as the constructor is hidden, is there any possibility that i could use that class? I googled the issue so much and now understand that the issue is @hide tag at the source file. is there any hope?

Comment: You need to be passed an instance of it.  If you were just to construct it, even if you could, it wouldn't magically have the right values.  Use TelephonyManager to get it.

Comment: Thank you so much Gabe Sechan for your reply, but the TelephonyManager does not have these method. I have tried many classes under anroid.telephony which have signal strength related methods(i.e SignalStrength, CellSignalStrength) but everytime i get the same hurdle. what can i do? How create and pass it? , thank you so much for your support

Comment: Sorry, its been a while since I did this, I forgot a step.  You need to add a PhoneStateListener via TelephonyManager.listen().  Then it will call your onSignalStrengthChanged function when the signal strength changes, passing it a SignalStrength object.

Comment: "public static final Creator<CellSignalStrengthGsm> CREATOR"          what does this line means. source: "http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/CellSignalStrengthGsm.html"

Comment: Thank you so much for your replies, I am going to try this. I am so grateful to you, I tried to vote but it says I need at least 15rpt